# How do you specify that a generic reference type is nullable when a subclass constraint is used in c# 8?

Tags: c#, generics, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

How do you specify that a generic reference type is nullable when a subclass constraint is used in c# 8? I have done some searching and I've found no useful results.

I know quite well that it is sufficient to add `where T: class` to specify that a generic type parameter `T` is a reference type. This way, the `nullable` reference annotations and warning features of C# 8 will work perfectly.

However, there's the case where the generic type parameter `T` is a sub-type of another class—say `SomeClass`. Now, when you add `where T: SomeClass`, you are basically telling the compiler that `T` is a reference type which is a sub-type of `SomeClass`, since a value type cannot be a sub-type of a reference type. However, the compiler doesn't seem to understand this when it comes to the `nullable` reference annotations and warning features of C# 8. How do you make it clear to the compiler?

Want to see some code? This is what I mean:

```cs
// this compiles
class ClassA<T> where T: class
{
    public GenericType<T?> DoSomething()
    {
        thrown new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

```cs
// this doesn't compile, but SomeClass is a class and it should work
class ClassA<T> where T: SomeClass
{
    // here, you get the classic:
    // Only non-nullable value type could be underlying of 'System.Nullable'
    // What this makes clear is that the compiler doesn't understand that
    // T is strictly a reference Type now
    public GenericType<T?> DoSomething()
    {
        thrown new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am unable to recreate this. If I enable nullable reference types then both of your code snippets compile. If I disable it then neither do.

Comment: I can't reproduce this either.

Comment: Tried building and it worked. It appears it's a VS/Resharper intellisense issue. I'm sorry.

Comment: Glad you got it working

Comment: @staa99 I'd also recommend you file a report to Resharper, this could confuse lots of other developers, and I'm sure they'd love to be able to get a report so they can fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll do that.

Comment: you have a constrain `where T : class`, with this `T?` of (`Nullable<T>`) make no sense. Shouldn't your constrain be `where T : struct`?

Comment: This is a C# 8 feature, Nullable reference types.

Comment: T? is not of Nullable<T> in this case

Comment: There is pretty similar issue on the ReSharper bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-476145, and it marked as fixed in upcoming R# 2019.3. So, you can check it in R# 2019.3 EAP https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/eap/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this so that it is easier for people to find. In my case, it wasn't actually a compilation issue, it was just Resharper's error highlighting that confused me.

To troubleshoot, just try building. If there are no errors and you use Resharper, then Resharper is the culprit. You can safely ignore it.

I'll file a report to Resharper so they can fix this soon.

Comment: It's not an issue. `SomeClassType?` or `Nullable<SomeClassType>` make no sense. All reference types are nullable by design.

Comment: @vasily.sib perhaps read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references

Comment: Yes, all reference types are nullable by design. However, in code, there are times when you want to differentiate between variables that can be null and those that can't. That's why the feature was introduced in c# 8

Comment: From the docs: Any variable where the ? is not appended to the type name is a non-nullable reference type. That includes all reference type variables in existing code when you have enabled this feature.

Comment: then maybe you should try nullable class constraint? Like `class ClassA<T> where T: class? { .. }`

Comment: @vasily.sib There is no `class?` constraint.  However there is a `notnull` constraint added with C# 8.

Comment: oh, sorry then @staa99

Comment: might be different on your machine but for me msbuild errors highlight the right bar in the middle, and resharper errors highlight the red bar on the right side. always a good idea to pay attention to which one (or both) is giving you errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the nullable reference types feature

One way is to enable `#nullable` with:

```
#nullable enable
```

Comment: I already enabled it in the csproj, just to be sure, I tried adding it with the #nullable directive too but it still doesn't work.